# Erro ao utilizar Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit

> t={movieName}&apikey=11111" must not have replace block. For
>   dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Este erro acontece ao tentar buscar um filme pelo nome, tenho os códigos abaixo, mas o erro permanece:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.omdbapi.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

@GET("?t={movieName}&apikey=11111")
Call<List<MovieResults>> getFilmesByName(@Query("movieName") String movieName);
```

Como fazer com que o nome do filme seja dinâmico, ou seja, pesquisado através de do que for escrito dentro de um edittext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para essa situação você deve usar o [`@Path`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html). Exemplo:

```
@GET("/?t={movieName}&apikey=11111")
Call<List<MovieResults>> getFilmesByName(@Path("movieName") String movieName);
```

Se não quiser, não há necessidade de colocar o parâmetro na URL como está fazendo explicitamente, basta usar a `@query` que é inserido automaticamente. Veja como deve ficar:

```
@GET("/?apikey=11111")
Call<List<MovieResults>> getFilmesByName(@Query("t") String movieName);
```

Comment: Com o Path o erro é o mesmo.

Comment: @HenriqueMendes geralmente funciona assim comigo. Tentou usando Query?!

Comment: Deu certo agora aqui,com a query dessa forma que passou, vou fazer mais alguns testes marco como resposta! Obrigado!

Comment: @HenriqueMendes Qualquer coisa, dê um toque! =D