# Passar mais de um parâmetro pela URL

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public interface service {

        @GET("?acao=R&tipo_refeicao={tipo}&data={data}")
        public void getCardapio(
           Callback<List<Cardapio>> getCardapio(@Query("tipo") int tipo, @Query("data") String data);
        )

}
```

Como eu faço para passar mais de um parâmetro?

Quero passar int e string que é uma data. Seria correto assim?

Como seria o correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como expliquei [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225501/35406) de como criar um `model` para receber os valores adequadamente, como precisa passar alguns parâmetros, você pode usar o [`@Query`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html). Veja abaixo

```
@GET("/restaurante")
Call<Cardapio.Conteudo> getCardapio(@Query("tipo") int tipo, @Query("data") String data);
```

Veja abaixo um exemplo em relação ao resultado da chamada acima:

```
/restaurante?tipo=SALADAS&data=2017-08-01
```

Respondi também uma outra pergunta [exemplificando o uso também do `@Path`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/223878/35406), no qual seria outra alternativa para resolver seu problema. Para mais detalhes e exemplos, veja mais sobre a notação do tipo [`Query` na documentação](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html).